# How do I create a lattice pattern in Cabinet Vision?

Tags: cad

I have a loop function that makes a line of diamond shaped holes based on the size of the parent object, and pre-defined variables, like shape length, minimum border and gap distance.
and the next line above it indents in so you get almost a stacking barrels pattern

Image below

[image]

The issue i am running into is when i get into.... half loops

for this example the image below is 15" tall

[image]

However manually in the have 15" height i can fit 2 rows

[image]

i am unable to figure out where in the loop steps to get this to fire off to get me the two lines of shapes.

below is my entire code for this.

The first set of shapes are created at ;***First Row***
The second set of shapes (that are indented in) starts at ;***SecondRow***

For Each S_DSLAB Part    -- searches for a specific part in the software
WINERACKROUTE            -- is a manually added variable to an object in the software
Dim DIAMOND as New ROUTE -- this is what creates the new shapes
DIAMOND.DZ = :DZ         -- each of these are parameters made for each new shape
:DZ              -- this ":" is telling the value to match the parent objects value of DZ

```
;Modifies Adjustable Shelf

 For Each S_DSLAB Part

 IF WINERACKROUTE = NULL THEN
 WINERACKROUTE = 0
 END IF
 
 IF WINERACKROUTE = 0 THEN
 EXIT
 END IF
 
IF !DIADX THEN
 DIADX<MEAS> = 4.25 
 DIADX<STYLE> = 1 
 DIADX<DESC> = 'DIAMOND SIZE' 
END IF
IF !DIAGAP THEN
 DIAGAP<MEAS> = 1 
 DIAGAP<STYLE> = 1 
 DIAGAP<DESC> = 'DIAMOND SPCING' 
END IF
IF !MINBORDER THEN
 MINBORDER<MEAS> = .25 
 MINBORDER<STYLE> = .25 
 MINBORDER<DESC> = 'MINIMUM BORDER' 
END IF

 
 CROSSDIA = SQRT(2*(DIADX^2))
 CROSSGAP = SQRT(2*(DIAGAP^2)) 
  XBORDER = 999
  YBORDER = 999     
  
LOOPX = 0
LOOPY = 0 
      
WHILE XBORDER > (CROSSDIA + CROSSGAP)/2 DO 
 LOOPX += 1 
 XBORDER := (  DX - MINBORDER - MINBORDER - (LOOPX*CROSSDIA) - ((LOOPX-1)*CROSSGAP)  )/2
END WHILE 
WHILE YBORDER > (CROSSDIA + CROSSGAP)/2 DO 
 LOOPY += 1 
 YBORDER := (  DY - MINBORDER - MINBORDER - (LOOPY*CROSSDIA) - ((LOOPY-1)*CROSSGAP)  )/2
END WHILE 


;***First Row***
 LOOPCUTY := 0 
 WHILE LOOPCUTY < LOOPY DO
  LOOPCUTX := 0
  LOOPCUTY += 1 
 WHILE LOOPCUTX < LOOPX DO
  LOOPCUTX += 1
  Dim DIAMOND as New ROUTE
  DIAMOND.TOOLID = 230
  DIAMOND.NAME = 'DIAMOND'
  DIAMOND.Visible<bool> := True
  DIAMOND.DX = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DY = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DZ = :DZ
  DIAMOND.X := MINBORDER+XBORDER+(LOOPCUTX-1)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)
  DIAMOND.Y := MINBORDER+YBORDER+(CROSSDIA/2)+(LOOPCUTY-1)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)
  DIAMOND.Z := 0
  DIAMOND.AX<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AY<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AZ<deg> = -45
  DIAMOND._FACEWP = 1
  DIAMOND._RCUT = 0
 END WHILE  
 END WHILE  

;***Second Row***
 LOOPCUTTY := 0 
 WHILE LOOPCUTTY < (LOOPY-1) DO
  LOOPCUTTX := 0
  LOOPCUTTY += 1 
 WHILE LOOPCUTTX < (LOOPX-1) DO
  LOOPCUTTX += 1
  Dim DIAMOND as New ROUTE
  DIAMOND.TOOLID = 230
  DIAMOND.NAME = 'DIAMOND'
  DIAMOND.Visible<bool> := True
  DIAMOND.DX = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DY = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DZ = :DZ
  DIAMOND.X := MINBORDER+XBORDER+(LOOPCUTTX-1)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)+(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)/2
  DIAMOND.Y := MINBORDER+YBORDER+(CROSSDIA/2)+(LOOPCUTTY-1)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)+(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)/2
  DIAMOND.Z := 0
  DIAMOND.AX<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AY<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AZ<deg> = -45
  DIAMOND._FACEWP = 1
  DIAMOND._RCUT = 0
 END WHILE  
 END WHILE
```

I have tried  modifying LOOPY and LOOPCUTY values but these only added 2 extra lines.. a "complete loop" of both "loop whiles" it would seem, and never just the second set.

This used to work in the past  and there was not a lot of extra or different lines of code to make this work (i dont have access to any previous revision of this to veriy what did make it work back then either). So I dont think I need to make a drastic overhaul of then 4 seperate loops and IF X>X checks to make this work.

edit/solution found

i have added a conditional size check for when i needed 2 rows, and hanged the Y-Loop in the second set to force 2 rows within this size range

what i then ran into is this applies to 2 parts, one being 1/4" smaller
So i changed DY values into CAB.DY values, which is the parent objects size instead of the childs part.  then the holes were offset in the smaller item, which i needed to offset. so then i added + or - Y times 2 or 3.
the parent items Y is 0, but the childs item Y is .125, which then centers these holes to the same position as the Childs

the child items purpose is to be a smaller pedastal that goes underneath, but still centered under the parent item.

It probably wont make sense to anyone not specifically using this software but i felt i would upload and "answer" this thread.

```
 For Each S_DSLAB Part

 IF WINERACKROUTE = NULL THEN
 WINERACKROUTE = 0
 END IF
 
 IF WINERACKROUTE = 0 THEN
 EXIT
 END IF
 
IF !DIADX THEN
 DIADX<MEAS> = 4.25 
 DIADX<STYLE> = 1 
 DIADX<DESC> = 'DIAMOND SIZE' 
END IF
IF !DIAGAP THEN
 DIAGAP<MEAS> = 1 
 DIAGAP<STYLE> = 1 
 DIAGAP<DESC> = 'DIAMOND SPCING' 
END IF
IF !MINBORDER THEN
 MINBORDER<MEAS> = .25 
 MINBORDER<STYLE> = .25 
 MINBORDER<DESC> = 'MINIMUM BORDER' 
END IF

 
 CROSSDIA = SQRT(2*(DIADX^2))
 CROSSGAP = SQRT(2*(DIAGAP^2)) 
  XBORDER = 999
  YBORDER = 999     
  
 ;------------ cut off bad sizes that dont work
  IF CAB.DY >= 15.5 or CAB.DY < 10.75 THEN
  
LOOPX = 0
LOOPY = 0 
  
  
  ;------------ started adding + 2*y to compensate for pedestals being smaller than door counterparts for Y positioning
      
WHILE XBORDER > (CROSSDIA + CROSSGAP)/2 DO 
 LOOPX += 1 
 XBORDER := (  DX - MINBORDER - MINBORDER - (LOOPX*CROSSDIA) - ((LOOPX-1)*CROSSGAP)  )/2
END WHILE 
WHILE YBORDER > (CROSSDIA + CROSSGAP)/2 DO 
 LOOPY += 1 
 YBORDER := (  CAB.DY - MINBORDER - MINBORDER - (LOOPY*CROSSDIA) - ((LOOPY-1)*CROSSGAP)  )/2 + (2*Y)
; YBORDER := (  DY - MINBORDER - MINBORDER - (LOOPY*CROSSDIA) - ((LOOPY)*CROSSGAP)  )/2
END WHILE 

 LOOPCUTY := 0 
 WHILE LOOPCUTY < LOOPY DO
  LOOPCUTX := 0
  LOOPCUTY += 1 
 WHILE LOOPCUTX < LOOPX DO
  LOOPCUTX += 1
  Dim DIAMOND as New ROUTE
  DIAMOND.TOOLID = 230;136
  DIAMOND.NAME = 'DIAMOND'
  DIAMOND.Visible<bool> := True
  DIAMOND.DX = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DY = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DZ = :DZ
  DIAMOND.X := MINBORDER+XBORDER+(LOOPCUTX-1)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)
  DIAMOND.Y := MINBORDER+YBORDER+(CROSSDIA/2)+(LOOPCUTY-1)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP) - (3*Y)
  DIAMOND.Z := 0
  DIAMOND.AX<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AY<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AZ<deg> = -45
  DIAMOND._FACEWP = 1
  DIAMOND._RCUT = 0
 END WHILE  
 END WHILE  

 LOOPCUTTY := 0 
 WHILE LOOPCUTTY < (LOOPY-1) DO
  LOOPCUTTX := 0
  LOOPCUTTY += 1 
 WHILE LOOPCUTTX < (LOOPX-1) DO
  LOOPCUTTX += 1
  Dim DIAMOND as New ROUTE
  DIAMOND.TOOLID = 230 ;136
  DIAMOND.NAME = 'DIAMOND'
  DIAMOND.Visible<bool> := True
  DIAMOND.DX = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DY = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DZ = :DZ
  DIAMOND.X := MINBORDER+XBORDER+(LOOPCUTTX-1)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)+(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)/2
  DIAMOND.Y := MINBORDER+YBORDER+(CROSSDIA/2)+(LOOPCUTTY-1)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)+(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)/2 - (3*Y)
  DIAMOND.Z := 0
  DIAMOND.AX<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AY<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AZ<deg> = -45
  DIAMOND._FACEWP = 1
  DIAMOND._RCUT = 0
 END WHILE  
 END WHILE  
END IF


;----- isolate off at certain Y heights to force 2 columns of openings
 IF CAB.DY < 15.5 AND CAB.DY >= 10.75 THEN
  
LOOPX = 0
LOOPY = 0
   
      
WHILE XBORDER > (CROSSDIA + CROSSGAP)/2 DO 
 LOOPX += 1 
 XBORDER := (  DX - MINBORDER - MINBORDER - (LOOPX*CROSSDIA) - ((LOOPX-1)*CROSSGAP)  )/2
END WHILE 
WHILE YBORDER > (CROSSDIA + CROSSGAP)/2 DO 
 LOOPY += 1 
 YBORDER := (  :Cab.DY - MINBORDER - MINBORDER - (LOOPY*CROSSDIA) - ((LOOPY-1)*CROSSGAP)  )/2 + (2*Y)
; older version:  YBORDER := (  DY - MINBORDER - MINBORDER - (LOOPY*CROSSDIA) - ((LOOPY)*CROSSGAP)  )/2
END WHILE 

 LOOPCUTY := 0 
 WHILE LOOPCUTY < LOOPY DO
  LOOPCUTX := 0
  LOOPCUTY += 1 
 WHILE LOOPCUTX < LOOPX DO
  LOOPCUTX += 1
  Dim DIAMOND as New ROUTE
  DIAMOND.TOOLID = 230;136
  DIAMOND.NAME = 'DIAMOND'
  DIAMOND.Visible<bool> := True
  DIAMOND.DX = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DY = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DZ = :DZ
  DIAMOND.X := MINBORDER+XBORDER+(LOOPCUTX-1)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)
  DIAMOND.Y := MINBORDER+YBORDER+(CROSSDIA/2)+(LOOPCUTY-1.25)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP) - (3*Y)
  DIAMOND.Z := 0
  DIAMOND.AX<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AY<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AZ<deg> = -45
  DIAMOND._FACEWP = 1
  DIAMOND._RCUT = 0
 END WHILE  
 END WHILE  

 LOOPCUTTY := 0
 WHILE LOOPCUTTY < (LOOPY) DO
  LOOPCUTTX := 0
  LOOPCUTTY += 1 
 WHILE LOOPCUTTX < (LOOPX-1) DO
  LOOPCUTTX += 1
  Dim DIAMOND as New ROUTE
  DIAMOND.TOOLID = 230 ;136
  DIAMOND.NAME = 'DIAMOND'
  DIAMOND.Visible<bool> := True
  DIAMOND.DX = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DY = DIADX
  DIAMOND.DZ = :DZ
  DIAMOND.X := MINBORDER+XBORDER+(LOOPCUTTX-1)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)+(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)/2
  DIAMOND.Y := MINBORDER+YBORDER+(CROSSDIA/2)+(LOOPCUTTY-1.25)*(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)+(CROSSDIA+CROSSGAP)/2 - (3*Y)
  DIAMOND.Z := 0
  DIAMOND.AX<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AY<deg> = 0
  DIAMOND.AZ<deg> = -45
  DIAMOND._FACEWP = 1
  DIAMOND._RCUT = 0
 END WHILE  
 END WHILE  

END IF
```

Comment: ...this is not SQL at all: SQL is not an imperative language. Just because a language uses UPPERCASE KEYWORDS does not mean it's SQL (after all, it could also be Cobol...)

Comment: ...is  there a reason you can't tell us exactly what programs and tooling you're using? Can you at least tell us the name and model of the CNC machine you're using?

Comment: Hello,
The software is in cabinet vision, this is a UCS that creates parts in what is essentially some form of 3d modeling software.

i dont know the specifics that defines SQL but a majority of the software and reporting do use SQL, and the UCS's  replicate some of those rulings.

it has nothing to do with whatever machine or cnc is is getting translated to because it can be translated to anything after the part geometry has been created - which is what this UCS program is doing, creating geometry.

Comment: as another edit... that was not my original title -- i dont know how it got changed but this is NOT a CNC Language.

Comment: well i apologize for the whole bother, and the somewhat random solution i came to for my needs on this - i have ended up with my own solution on this, albeit a bit convoluted, hopefully i can edit my origional post here and add my finalized code.

Answer (score 0):

Opps... My answer I posted back in as an edit on the original post

here are some images that show my final results and might help show the parent child relationship.

the child is smaller, but has larger holes, and is offset .125 in x and Y from the parent item, but the holes for both still need to be centered on each other

[image]

[image]

[image]